# MATLAB - resizing matrix using matrix multiplication and not the RESIZE command

Tags: matlab, matrix

For a specific problem, I need to design the resizing of a matrix process using multiplication of matrices alone. 
Given a matrix of *A* of dimensions (a*b,1) where a and b are integers, I need to find a way to resize *A* to dimensions (a,b) like this:

M*A*N = resize(A,a,b)

where dim(M) = (a,a*b) and dim(N) = (1,b). It doesn't have to be two matrices but I don't think it is possible any other way.

Comment: You mean you can't use `reshape`? That's a strange limitation. Why not?

Comment: shoelzer, it's an optimization problem. So I need to somehow linearize this. So I need to represent stuff as vectors and matrices and do some manipulation.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...Could you post what and how you're trying to optimize?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Ha ha...:). No, I don't think there is a better solution to the actual problem.

Comment: @SPRajagopal: Still, could you post what you're trying to accomplish, instead of how you think it should be solved?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis It's part of a paper I'm working on jointly with a professor. That's why I cannot post it. I was hoping my question was a simple one - it's just matrices. Apparently not. :D Anyway thanks.

Comment: @SPRajagopal: Surely you can remove all the irrelevant details and write a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? We can only really help and tell if you've simply overlooked a programming technique if you post what you try to do (without the specifics)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) or [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html), you need to do your manipulation for each element of `A` separately.

There is no such `M` and `N` that you are searching for.

Suppose:

```
resh_A = M*A*N;
```

Let's study one row of this equation. Assume one row of `M*A` :

```
temp_i = M(i, :) * A;
```

Since `M(i, :)` is **`1 x a*b`** and `A` is **`a*b x 1`**; `temp_i` whould be a **`1 x 1`** matrix.

Now `temp_i * N` should result in the `ith` row of your result (or `resh_A`).
Thus `resh_A` will look like:

(note `N` is **`1 x b`**)

```
   temp_1 * N % row1
   temp_2 * N % row2
   temp_3 * N % row3
   ...
```

which is not a general matrix (it's a matrix with rank 1).

Comment: In Matlab parlance, column and row vectors, scalars, and empty matrices (with dimension <= 2) are all "matrices," e.g., `ismatrix(1)`, `ismatrix([1 2 3])`, `ismatrix([1;2;3])`, and `ismatrix([])`. N-D arrays are not.

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely true. Accepting your answer because I obviously don't have one. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear. Hope it helps.
@horchler: I corrected the notations. Thanks.

Comment: @horchler: Hey, just found this: [`isscalar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isscalar.html) and just wanted to let you know about it! ;)

Comment: Yep. Very useful. `isscalar(1) == ismatrix(1)` of course. The `isscalar` function is actually much older than `ismatrix` (v7.0 vs. v7.11). My point was't about these functions or linear algebra, but in the context of Matlab code that all 2-D arrays (scalars, vectors, and matrices) are treated as matrices and can be indexed as such. Sorry if I wasn't very clear.